# Understanding Orchard placement.info files

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I'm new to orchard development and spent the last week studying it. I'm having a hard time in understanding some concepts, such as placement.info files.

I've read the article [Understanding placement info](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-placement-info) from the project site and the section from the book "Orchard up and running" related to it.

What I understand:

- Placement info files work on the content item level. It is used to reorder the rendering of the fields and content parts;
- This file has three main tags: placement (basically a wrapper), match(which defines if the rules will be applied to the summary or detail display) and place (which effectively defines the placement rules);

What I don't understand:

- How do I define the order of the tags? In the "place" tags I see "Content:Before", "Content:After.7", "Content:2.9" and some other rules. What does it mean to define "Place Parts_Tags_ShowTags="Header:after.7"/"? Is the placement file capable of moving parts to different zones?

---

I'm getting a bit frustrated using it. I don't know if I'm not using the right material (they seem very brief and/or outdated). If so, could someone suggest me some links?

I'd really appreciate some help, guys..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name of the attribute is the shape name (usually as returned by a part driver), and the value is where to send that shape. It is a zone name, followed by a colon, and then ordering. The zone name can start with a slash if you want to target a top-level zone (those are defined in the Layout.cshtml file), like this: `/AsideSecond:1`. The ordering can be a special number, or a dotted sequence. For example, 1.1 comes after 1 but before 2. 1.1.1 would come after 1.1 and before 1.2, etc. after and before can also be used to send a shape after or before everything else.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Bertrand. After some more reading, I'm starting to better understand orchard concepts.

Comment: Thanks for the note about starting with a slash to target a top-level zone, this tip was missing from http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-placement-info